# I have 2 different types of array and unable to find the difference

Tags: arrays, codeigniter-3

This is my first array : 
`[ 'full_name' =>'Mukesh' ,'username' => 'mukesh@123' ]`

This is my second array
`Array ( [full_name] => mukesh [username] => mukesh@123)`

My second array i got from codeignitor via $this->input->post();
Now , my question is what's the difference in both of these and how to achieve the first array type in codeigniter. 
I have a lot of fields in my view.

Comment: Well I think there is no diff. as first one is human generated and second one is code's output. Still change both types to toString() so forcefully text will be in string type

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both array. Both are same.

$data = [ 'full_name' =>'Mukesh' ,'username' => 'mukesh@123' ];
print_r($data);

for above print display is
Array ( [full_name] => Mukesh [username] => mukesh@123 )